# how to pass many arguments through a command function (do_)

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I want to code a simple command that could take 3 arguments for a text adventure game.

Basically at the prompt, I would type 'use key unlock door' and it would run a particular block.

Here is what I coded but it does not work:

```
def do_use(self, tool, action, object):

    if tool == 'key':
        if action == 'unlock':
            if object == 'door':
                print("seems like it works!")
            else:
                print("nope 1")
        else:
            print("nope 2")
    else:
        print("nope 3")
```

Notes: the rest of the commands work fine. I imported cmd
and the following is the main code:

```
class Game(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

    ....


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        g = Game()
        g.cmdloop()
```

At the prompt, when I type:

```
>>> use key unlock door
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: do_use() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

The code would work if it would print:

```
seems like it works!
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What seems to be wrong? How do you judge "it does not work"?

Comment: good question: well, at the prompt, when I type >>> use key unlock door, I get an error message saying:  TypeError: do_use() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Comment: You haven't showed what calls ``do_use``

Comment: its a built-in command that works with the cmd module which I have imported.  I have other commands like do_take, do_ask that work fine. You can find more about the cmd module at https://wiki.python.org/moin/CmdModule

Comment: Reading that documentation, it looks like all of the commands just take in a single string, and you have to parse the string yourself. Your command is defined as taking 4 arguments (including ``self``), and ``cmd`` is calling it with ``self, input``, which is 2.

Comment: to aruisdante;  great! any suggestions on how I could parse the string myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading that documentation, it looks like all of the commands just take in a single string, and you have to parse the string yourself. Your command is defined as taking 4 arguments (including `self`), and `cmd` is calling it with `self, input`, which is 2. I think could get the result you want with the following:

```
def do_use(self, user_input):
    args = user_input.split()
    if len(args) != 3:
        print "*** invalid number of arguments"
    else:
        tool, action, obj = args
 # Do the rest of your code here
```

Comment: Bravo!!  I had to change some of the variables, arguments because they were reserved keywords. Like 'input and object'.. changed that to 'params, thing'. Great job aruisdante!!